# Basic authentication without configuration file and module in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, basic-authentication

I am working on asp.net project in which basic authentication is being used.
There is nothing written in the configuration file, any source code file, ultimately code is not responsible for authentication.

Even if I pointed application to the blank directory on IIS, though when I run the application it authenticates first and then shows page not found error.

I am so confused, how the basic authentication is working here.
Is there any service being used in backend on the windows? or how it is validating the authentication? or any setting is already there in IIS(chances are very less, I cross checked and found no such settings.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is too vague. The best thing you can do is open the solution in Visual Studio, place a breakpoint in Main and step the code. At some point it should hit the authentication section.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think there is nothing written in the code for authentication as I already said if I point to the blank directory is authenticating first then gives error. May be it is happening through the Active Directory.

Comment: In that case go to the directory right mouse click and look at the security tab. Ensure the correct permissions are given.